# Set default value for auto-implemented property

Tags: c#, getter-setter

Say I have an auto-implemented property

```
public int SheetNum { get; set; }
```

Is there anyway to set the default value of `SheetNum` to 1, so it would be like

```
private int sheetNum = 1;

public int SheetNum
{
    set { this.sheetNum = value; }
    get { return this.sheetNum; }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're almost there; you just have to initialize the value in the constructor:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Foo = 1;
    }

    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```